# Google Assistant on AndroidTV doesn't display table

Tags: actions-on-google, android-tv

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#table_cards), tables should be supported on these devices:

"Supported on surfaces with the actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT capability."

My AndroidTV has that capability but it doesn't display a table even though it appears in the simulator. Does anyone know what the problem might be?
Thank you in advance.